# Why React Fiber.memoriedStates is a linked list rather than an array

Tags: reactjs, react-fiber

Why is the storage method of React Hook on the Fiber node a linked list instead of an array? What are the unique advantages of using a linked list?

This is a question I encountered during the interview and I didn't quite understand it。

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Linked list are better in traversal, insertion and deletion operation than the arrays which help virtual dom to manipulated states and components.

For more, just assume deletion of 0th index element in an array and in linked list both have different performance and react need to fast refresh of every component it will not wait for arrays insertion and deletion for mounting and un-mounting the component in Dom.

for more ->

[First Fiber](https://github.com/acdlite/react-fiber-architecture)

[Depth](https://angularindepth.com/posts/1007/the-how-and-why-on-reacts-usage-of-linked-list-in-fiber-to-walk-the-components-tree)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).